Understanding php-fpm resources config
I currently have a stack with PHP-FPM and Nginx running on ECS EC2.
After observing some metrics, I noticed that the Memory and CPU usage of my stack is low.
However, when I tried reducing my tasks from 13GB to 9GB, I saw a significant increase in connections caused by PHP-FPM. Could someone explain why this happens, even though my previous resource usage was low, allowing room for adjustments?
www.conf:
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 150
pm.start_servers = 4
pm.min_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_spare_servers = 8
pm.max_requests = 500

ECS Task Config:
TASK_MEMORY="9216"    

TASK_MEMORY_RESERVATION="8192"

old values
TASK_MEMORY="13516"    

TASK_MEMORY_RESERVATION="12288"

PHP-FPM:

Container-CPU:

MEMORY-RSS:


[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.

@Barmar this looks more like a PHP configuration issue than a Linux configuration question. I don't even see anything about Linux in the question. This looks perfectly on-topic to me.

@MarkB I thought it looked like an NGINX config issue, but could be wrong.

@Barmar it's a PHP-FPM configuration issue, with one mention that they are also using Nginx.

I appreciate anyone who can help me understand this behavior. Anyway, I've created a post in server-fault. Understanding php-fpm resources config

@PabloMarques where are you getting the values from to display those graphs in PHP-FPM image?

@abdurrehman Hi, DataDog.
